# How to check a specific spot in a string in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I check to see if the ninth character in a string is a letter or a number.

For example, in "25006070TR" I want to return Yes or something resembling that it is a letter.  On the other hand, in "250060708R" I want a "No" or something saying number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement and combinations of substr and regexp_like, something like:

```
with sample_data as (select '25006070TR' str from dual union all
                     select '250060708R' str from dual union all
                     select '25006070#R' str from dual union all
                     select '25006070 R' str from dual union all
                     select '12345' str from dual)
select str,
       case when regexp_like(substr(str, 9, 1), '\d') then 'Digit'
            when regexp_like(substr(str, 9, 1), '[[:alpha:]]') then 'Letter'
            when substr(str, 9, 1) is null then 'Empty'
            else 'Special character'
       end ninth_char_type
from   sample_data;


STR        NINTH_CHAR_TYPE  
---------- -----------------
25006070TR Letter           
250060708R Digit            
25006070#R Special character
25006070 R Special character
12345      Empty
```

Obviously, if you're doing this directly in PL/SQL, you can just embed the case statement directly into the PL/SQL; you wouldn't need to switch to SQL.

If you're fetching the string from a table, then you should keep the case expression in a SQL statement.